# Can I include a mod declaration and also have it as a file in a subdirectory?

Tags: rust

If I have a module `a` and in the file `a.rs` I declare a module `b`

```
    //a.rs
    ...
    mod b{}
```

Can I then have a `b.rs` file nested under the `a/` directory?

e.g.

```
   /foo
     src/
       main.rs
       a.rs
       a/
          b.rs
```

I'm reading the rust book [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html) b
and I'm trying to understand how this works

Comment: Yes, assuming you do `mod b;` and not `mod b {}` (which declares an inner module `b`). However, asking such question with something you can so easily try yourself is feels like not appreciating the effort that people here invest for you, for free. If you can't test now, go on and test later.

Comment: Thank you. I weighted the complexity of the question vs my ability to test it ( not possible for several days) before posting. Added your comment as answer and attributed to you. Is your prefer add an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer by @Chayim Friedman*

Yes, assuming you do `mod b;` and not `mod b {}` (which declares an inner module b).